# How do I modify a bat file in such a way as the environment and console instance remains open upon the scripts completion?

Tags: python, batch-file

I wrote a nice .bat file that runs a python script:

```
cd C:\ProgramData\Anaconda64\condabin 
call conda activate
call conda activate py37_32
SET PyPathName=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda64\envs\py37_32\python.exe
SET ScriptName=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\path_to_my_script\my_script.py
%PyPathName% %ScriptName%
```

When I click on the .bat file, I get the expected result in the terminal window that opens up:

```
C:\Users\my_username\path_to_batfile>cd C:\ProgramData\Anaconda64\condabin

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda64\condabin>call conda activate

(base) C:\ProgramData\Anaconda64\condabin>call conda activate py37_32

(py37_32) C:\ProgramData\Anaconda64\condabin>SET PyPathName=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda64\envs\py37_32\python.exe

(py37_32) C:\ProgramData\Anaconda64\condabin>SET ScriptName=C:\Users\my_username\path_to_my_script\my_script.py

(py37_32) C:\ProgramData\Anaconda64\condabin>C:\ProgramData\Anaconda64\envs\py37_32\python.exe C:\Users\my_username\path_to_my_script\my_script.py
```

Everything is fine, the script works well and all. Except that I would like to interact with the results coming from the script, using python. Example: in the `my_script.py` script, I am receiving data from a websocket and storing it in a pandas time series. To give a concrete example, I'd like to type at any given moment:

`my_series.plot()`

This is a special case of something I'd like to do. But really, my question is rather general: is there any way I can type python code in the terminal window that opens up when running the bat file, such that I can use the results of the script?

I can provide additional details about the script itself.

**EDIT**:
It seems that there is some confusion in the way I phrased the question hence here a more specific solution taken from one of the comments.

How do I modify the bat file in such a way as the environment and console instance remains open upon the scripts completion?

Comment: The 'terminal' window isn't an interactive interface for you to use along side your running your python script, it is dedicated to it. You could interact with it once your script has completed, as long as you've invoked the script in such a way as the environment and console instance remains open upon the scripts completion. This site is not here to provide general programming advice, it is to assist other programmers with a solution to a specific replicable issue with their own code.

Comment: I modified the question to make it clearer, I hope.

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly, just run the script from the command line instead of double-clicking it and the console will stay open.

Comment: @SomethingDark that is what I do, but I have to distribute it to others that would rather have it as bat on which they just click.

Comment: You can try to run Python in debug mode (by accessing an input arg in batch or other way) and setup a breakpoints somewhere in script. But your users should have to know how to use debug. In debug mode they might run any code.

Comment: Last line changed to `%PyPathName% -i %ScriptName%` invokes inspection mode after the Python script has finished. You can then try `my_series.plot()` as the Python environment remains open for interaction.

Comment: @frost-nzcr4 problem is my users

Comment: @michael_heath good one. what does the -i stand for? con you point me somewhere where it is explained?

Comment: Look at [Python Docs: Command line and environment](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html). You can also display help about arguments with `python -h` at a command prompt. `-i` is **i**nspection argument.

Comment: just to say that i ended up using ```-i```, so if you put it into an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Add a simple line:

```
cmd /k
```

This will open a new cmd instance (using the same window), which inherits the environment you just set, and will not close because of the `/k`. See `cmd /?` for details.

Comment: i will have a look at the cmd /?.